# Django обновление формы

Tags: python-3.x, django

```
class FlightForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:

    model = Flight
    generator = structGenerator.Generator()

    AIRPORTS_LIST = tuple(zip([_["name"] for _ in generator.airports_dict.values()],
                              [_["name"] for _ in generator.airports_dict.values()]))
    MODELS_LIST = tuple(zip([_["name"] for _ in generator.models_dict.values()],
                            [_["name"] for _ in generator.models_dict.values()]))
    COMPANIES_LIST = tuple(zip([_["name"] for _ in generator.company_dict.values()],
                               [_["name"] for _ in generator.company_dict.values()]))
    CLASSES = (("W", "W"), ("S", "S"), ("Y", "Y"), ("B", "B"), ("H", "H"), ("K", "K"),
               ("L", "L"), ("J", "J"), ("C", "C"), ("D", "D"), ("Z", "Z"), ("I", "I"))
    print(MODELS_LIST)
    class DateInputt(DateInput):
        input_type = 'date'

    class DateTimeInputt(DateTimeInput):
        input_type = 'datetime-local'

    widgets = {
        'flight_number': TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
        'flight_airport_of_arrival': Select(attrs={"class": "form-control"}, choices=AIRPORTS_LIST),
        'flight_airport_of_departure': Select(attrs={"class": "form-control"}, choices=AIRPORTS_LIST),
        'flight_time_of_arrival': DateTimeInputt(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
        'flight_time_of_departure': DateTimeInputt(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
        'aircraft_ID': TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
        'aircraft_classes_of_service': SelectMultiple(attrs={"class": "form-control"}, choices=CLASSES),
        'aircraft_company': Select(attrs={"class": "form-control"}, choices=COMPANIES_LIST),
        'aircraft_model': Select(attrs={"class": "form-control"}, choices=MODELS_LIST),
        'aircraft_release_date': DateInputt(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
    }
```

Есть такая форма, с полями типа Select. Столкнулся с проблемой, что надо изменять содержимое полей AIRPORTS_LIST, MODELS_LIST.., чтобы менялся список выбираемых обьектов в форме.
Но не могу того добиться, новая информация возвращается из   generator.models_dict.values() и других методов, но в форме все остается без изменений на странице. Изменения появляются только после пересборки проекта.
Есть ли возможность это исправить?

Comment: Определение класса формы происходит один раз - при её загрузке, то есть при старте проекта. Чтобы данные изменялись при каждом создании формы, присваивание полям класса нужно переместить в его конструктор.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Переопределите виджеты полей в `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):  
    AIRPORTS_LIST = tuple(zip([_["name"] for _ in generator.airports_dict.values()],
                              [_["name"] for _ in generator.airports_dict.values()]))
    self.fields['flight_airport_of_arrival'].widget = Select(attrs={"class": "form-control"}, choices=AIRPORTS_LIST)
```

Comment: Спасибо, правда я так до конца и не понял как этот метод работает с __init__, но во views работает)

Comment: Метод init у класса вызывается в момент инициализации нового экземпляра класса, в вашем случае это в момент `form = FlightForm(*args)`. И этот init метод надо переопредить у класса формы